# API workflow to get data as a graph

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

I am modeling a graph in neo4J to store all the relationships/queries of a API system. so e.g., An API `API 1` - `GET:/api/employee/{email}` takes email and returns `id`. A second API `API 2` `GET:/api/employee/salary/{e_id}` takes `EmployeeId` and returns `Salary`. The graph representation looks like this.
[image]

Given an email, for example, I would like to write a query to figure out everything that can be extracted from this system. For the graph above, the output would be something like:

```
API 1 - input - email
API 1 - output - employee_id
API 2 - input - employee_id
API 2 - output - Salary
```

If there are better/shorter paths which would output a particular data item, the algorithm need to suggest that. I believe what I need is a variation of single source shortest path algorithm, but I am not sure how to proceed. If there is a better way to model this graph to improve the query performance, please let me know

Comment: Thoughts on remodeling this so that the only nodes are the blue ones and the green ones are properties of the blue ones? get the graph to something in the lines of https://cs.iupui.edu/~fgsong/LearnHPC/sssp/deltaStep.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the labels in the graph are `:Api` and `:Parameter` and the nodes all have a `name` property then this Cypher will return all of the APIs and lists of their input and output parameters:

```
MATCH (a:Api)
WITH a AS apis
MATCH (apis)-[:INPUT]->(ip:Parameter)
WITH apis, COLLECT(ip.name) AS inputParams
MATCH (apis)-[:OUTPUT]->(op:Parameter)
WITH apis, inputParams, COLLECT(op.name) AS outputParams
RETURN apis.name as apiName, inputParams, outputParams
```